# Java ThreadPool construct - "When thread gets created"?

Tags: java, concurrency

Members, I was going through the ThreadPool construct(ThreadPoolExecutors) being used instead of instantiation of new thread every-time. My questions are :

- When does JVM actually creates & start new thread ?
- How does JVM assign new Runnable task to already started thread ?

Comment: guys, while its good to share your opinion on the question asked. It would also be good to share the reason for downvote as it would help me to keep in mind for any further queries in future.

Answer (score -1):

When does JVM actually creates & start new thread?

It depends on the framework that you use. If you are using `ThreadPoolExecutor` that located to JDK since 1.5, the thread pool is created when first task submitted, not when `ThreadPoolExecutor` created. Code snippet below comes from `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` :

```java
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        if (command == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        /*
         * Proceed in 3 steps:
         *
         * 1. If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, try to
         * start a new thread with the given command as its first
         * task.  The call to addWorker atomically checks runState and
         * workerCount, and so prevents false alarms that would add
         * threads when it shouldn't, by returning false.
         *
         * 2. If a task can be successfully queued, then we still need
         * to double-check whether we should have added a thread
         * (because existing ones died since last checking) or that
         * the pool shut down since entry into this method. So we
         * recheck state and if necessary roll back the enqueuing if
         * stopped, or start a new thread if there are none.
         *
         * 3. If we cannot queue task, then we try to add a new
         * thread.  If it fails, we know we are shut down or saturated
         * and so reject the task.
         */
        int c = ctl.get();
        if (workerCountOf(c) < corePoolSize) {
            if (addWorker(command, true))
                return;
            c = ctl.get();
        }
        if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {
            int recheck = ctl.get();
            if (! isRunning(recheck) && remove(command))
                reject(command);
            else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0)
                addWorker(null, false);
        }
        else if (!addWorker(command, false))
            reject(command);
    }
```

How does JVM assign new Runnable task to already started thread?

Take `ThreadPoolExecutor` for example, it put task in `workQueue` firstly, which is a `BlockingQueue` and created when `ThreadPoolExecutor` created, and then, when one of the worker threads in thread pool complete last task, it will try to fetch a task from the `workQueue`.

But pay attention to that, all workers are firstly created with a initial task, they do the job while they are created at once.

```java
    private boolean addWorker(Runnable firstTask, boolean core) {
```

Comment: Guys, I'm trying to solve the problem in a appropriate way I think. If there is something wrong please leave comments while the vote down, it will be more helpful.